# How do I fill this case for a view with a protocol

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a view like this:

```
struct Panel<T:MyProtocol>: View {
  @ObservedObject private var model:T

  init(_ model:T) {
    self.model = model
  }
```

This and other views will show as `.sheet`.

Then I have this:

```
class SheetController:ObservableObject {

  enum SheetToDisplay {
    case panel
    case about
    case check
  }

  @Published var displaySheet = false
  var sheetToDisplay:SheetToDisplay?
}
```

Om my `ContentView` I have a variable like this:

```
  var sheetController: SheetController()
```

So, when I am about to show one of these views as sheets I have to do this, for example:

```
sheetController.sheetToDisplay = .panel
sheetController.displaySheet = true
```

on the module deciding which sheet has to be displayed, I have to have something like this:

```
case .panel(let model):
  Panel(model)
```

but for that to work, that `case panel` on the enum has to be something like

```
  case panel(_ model:T)
```

error on the last line: "cannot find T is scope"

How do I declare that `case panel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, add `MyProtocol` constraint in `SheetController`.

```
class SheetController<T: MyProtocol>: ObservableObject {  // <-- Here
    
    enum SheetToDisplay {
        case panel(_ model:T)
    }
    
    @Published var displaySheet = false
    var sheetToDisplay: SheetToDisplay?
}
```